# Parse RSS <link> to use as a source

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

OK so im trying to have a webpage that rotates every 30 seconds now i have what i need for this but instead of using an array like in what i have now see code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Rotating Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
html, body, iframe {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}    
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pages = new Array(); // this will hold your pages
pages[0] = 'MY-LINK-HERE';
pages[1] = 'MY-LINK-HERE';
pages[2] = 'MY-LINK-HERE';
pages[3] = 'MY-LINK-HERE';
pages[4] = 'MY-LINK-HERE';
pages[5] = 'MY-LINK-HERE';

var time = 30; // set this to the time you want it to rotate in seconds

// do not edit
var i = 1;
function setPage()
{
    if(i == pages.length)
    {
        i = 0;  
    }
    document.getElementById('holder').setAttribute('src',pages[i]);
    i++;
}    
setInterval("setPage()",time * 1000);
// do not edit
</script>
</head>

<body>
<iframe id="holder" src="MY-SPLASH-PAGE-HERE" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

where in MY-LINK-HERE for the pages array i would like to use my rss link and get the list of links and add them to the pages array or something similar

my rss link is http://directitpros.com/cbm/wp/?feedpages

so i just want to load the  text in the pages variable

Comment: Your question is very vague. What is "your" RSS link? Are you asking how to get links from an RSS feed? Please edit your question to say exactly what you want to do, so we know how to help.

Comment: Can I use jQuery :-)? Other thing, your link works when it wants! sometimes yes others not

Comment: sure as long as i can use it to request the page ie like var = pages in my axample i just need the rss item link

Comment: I cannot get your rss link to work.

Comment: its the same as any rss this is the only one i have as of right now but i want to parse rss->channel->item->link

Comment: @Alcatraz try to do a simple example that process your RSS URL and make sure if you can parse the response, maybe using PHP or what you want (you will notice that it won't be possible) Well, I got what you need, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time but I got it (tested and working)

- This example uses jQuery and jGFeed.
- jGFeed is a plugin for jQuery to do anything you want with RSS feeds.
- In the HTML source you can get the URL of the plugin to save it.

**Observations:**

**1.** Your RSS link is not working properly, please check it! 
(http://directitpros.com/cbm/wp/?feedpages)

When using your link I receive this error from the plugin I am using in browser console:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'feed' of null"
```

**2.** Make sure the links you want to use in iframe are able to browse by iframe:

**Example:**

If URLs are not able to browse by iframe you will get this message in your browser console and your iframe will be empty:

```
"Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."
```

**3.** If you find a working RSS url and links from it fit the above requirements, use this live example I made to test:

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/qWdqc/

(Check browser console and check messages that will appear)

---

Let's go with the code :-)

**HTML:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15208254/stackoverflow/jquery.jgfeed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<iframe id="holder" src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>​
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body, iframe {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}​
```

**JS:**

```
// Array containing pages
var pages = new Array();

// Time in seconds to rotate pages
var time = 30;

// Variable for loop purpose
var i = 1;

$(function(){

    $.jGFeed('http://working-rss-url',
      function(feeds){

        // Check for feeds
        if(!feeds){
          // There was an error, remote url not ok or no feeds
          return false;
        }

        // Do whatever you want with feeds here
        for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
          var entry = feeds.entries[i];
          // Fill array with RSS entries
          pages.push(entry);
        }

        // If array contains urls
        if(pages.length != 0){
            // Rotate pages every 'x' seconds
            setInterval(function() {
                if(i == pages.length){
                   i = 0;  
                }
                // Replace iframe scr with RSS entry link every 'x' seconds
                $('#holder').attr('src', pages[i].link);
                i++;
            }, time * 1000);
        }

    }, 5); // Number of feeds you want to recover

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works amazing and thank you for putting your time into this i know its be explained so many times but trying to locate information on how to do such things was not easy... again thanks for your help

Comment: @Alcatraz No problem :-) I am here to help.